Why must the generic parameter list in an impl block be the same as the generic parameter list in a struct?
struct StructName<T, U> {
    field1: T,
    field2: U,
}

impl<T, U> StructName<T, U> {
    
}

As in the code above, the generic argument list in the impl block and the struct generic argument list must match, otherwise the Rust compiler will give an error.
I have three questions:

Why do they need to be consistent?
What is the relationship between them?
Given that they are consistent, why do they need to be explicitly repeated instead of the compiler implicitly filling the impl block with the generic argument list in the struct?


StructName is a type constructor: given two types T and U, it constructs the type StructName<T, U>.  There's no requirement to always name generic types the same as they are named in the struct definition: the impl could for example name them X and Y or Foo and Bar; nor is there any requirement for implementations to be generic: you could for example have an impl StructName<u32, String> or some combination of concrete and generic types.  Because of this flexibility, it's necessary for an impl to be explicit about exactly what type it is for.

"otherwise the Rust compiler will give an error" - can you provide an example?

The question is not the same, but the answer is probably helpful to you: Calling a method of a struct that was specified as generic, in Rust

They do not need to be consistent; this is perfectly valid:
struct StructName<T, U> {
    field1: T,
    field2: U,
}

impl<A, B> StructName<A, B> {}

The brackets in impl<...> are to declare what generic parameters you are going to use within the block and StructName<...> is where you associate those generic parameters to the struct definition. In the above case, you can use A to refer to the first type parameter for StructName. To avoid confusion, you would probably avoid using different names needlessly.
However, sometimes a distinction is needed. For example, you can implement associated items when StructName's parameters are the same like so:
impl<T> StructName<T, T> {
    // field1 and field2 are the same type, T
}

Or in the case that the first parameter may have special associated items if it were u32:
impl<U> StructName<u32, U> {
    // field1 is a u32
}

Or if both are, then you wouldn't need <...> in the impl at all:
impl StructName<u32, u32> {
    // field1 and field2 are u32s
}

It is most common that the impl parameters are the same as the struct parameters, but the syntax provides a level of abstraction in cases like above that are specialized.

By this I mean why does impl<T, U> need to match the generic arguments in the StructName<T, U> that follows it? If you had the following code, it would throw an error:impl<T, U> StructName<A, B> {}

"The brackets in impl<...> are to declare what generic parameters you are going to use..." - in that sample A and B haven't been declared (assuming there are no actual types in scope with those names) so the compiler has no idea what they are supposed to mean.

Thank you. I think I understand the question.
